# Transferring data in bytes from one array to another in C

Tags: c, arrays

So I have two dynamically allocated integer variables (A and B). Each of them is of size 12 which makes each of 48 bytes. I want to transfer data from one to another in bytes basis and want to complete the transfer in 32 rounds (loops). I would describe below what I am trying to achieve:

- Round 1 : First 2 Bytes (bytes 1 and 2) of array A to Array B
- Round 2 : Next 2 Bytes (bytes 3 and 4) of array A to array B

Goes on transferring 2 Bytes up to round 16. In round 16, 31st and 32nd bytes would be transferred.

Then from round 17 to 32 transfer rate would be 1 Bytes/ Round, i.e.

- Round 17 : 33rd Byte from A to B
- Round 18 : 34th Byte from A to B

......

- Round 32 : 48th Byte from A to B

Below I have attached a code snippet :

```
int *A,*B;

    A = (int *)malloc(12*sizeof(int));
    B = (int *)malloc(12*sizeof(int));

    for(int i= 0;i<12;i++)
     A[i] = i+1;

    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){

      if(i<16)
        //Transfer two byte from A to B in first 16 rounds, 2 bytes/round
      else
       // transfer 1 byte from A to B in next 16 rounds, 1 byte/round
    }

    free(A);
    free(B);
```

I can understand that this might be achieved using `memcpy` but I am confused in performing the address calculation. I am not sure if I am taking the correct approach. Please let me know if I am clear enough in my explanation. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's the point in all of this shuffling-around of data? In general, anything you can do to avoid copying data is good.

Comment: Actually I need it for a different purpose which is bit more complicated to explain. But this is the basic version of what I would be needed finally. So apparently it may sound a bit odd, but this is a kind of test program I am writing and would be implementing this technique in somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But the actually data would be supplied to me as int, float or double. So that is why I cannot work on char*

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: `A` and `B` are **not** integer variables, but pointers to `int`, resp pointers to arrays of 12 `int`s.

Comment: Try to transfer in larger blocks when possible, using [memcpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `char*` pointers to access individual bytes of the buffers, and `uint16_t*` for the 2-byte blocks.

```
char *cA = (char *)A;
char *cB = (char *)B;

uint16_t *iA = (uint16_t *)A;
uint16_t *iB = (uint16_t *)B;

for(int i=0;i<32;i++){

    if(i<16) {
        //Transfer two byte from A to B in first 16 rounds, 2 bytes/round
        iB[i] = iA[i];
    }
    else {
        // transfer 1 byte from A to B in next 16 rounds, 1 byte/round
        cB[16 + i] = cA[16 + i];
    }
 }
```

Comment: I can understand that this could have done using char* but i was wondering if there is a procedure to perform this using int* ?

Comment: You'll have to cast the `int*` to `char*` to access individual bytes, so it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: You could access the `int` and then use bit shifting and masking, but that's more complicated.

Comment: There is one more thing I was wondering if could be done. Within the if statement if the copy of two bytes can be in single step rather than doing in two separate steps without using memcpy.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `uint16_t*` for the first 16 steps.

Comment: This still seems like a very weird way to do it. None of your comments above really explain why you can't just use `memcpy` to copy the whole thing at once.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually I am going to apply a technique similar to this in a platform which doesn't support memcpy.